# svg image not working in safari 5.1.7 (windows)

Tags: svg, safari

svg image not working in safari 5.1.7 (windows) . But when i open the svg image in safari and then visit the site, the image is displayed there.

Comment: Please be more clear as to what your problem is.  What does "not working" mean?  You say "visit the site" - what site?

Comment: I am developing a website in which i am using svg images, like this      <img src="web_develop.svg" />, Now when i visit the site in chrome its working fine but when visit it in the safari, svg images is not displayed there. But if i open the svg image in the safari then its displayed in the site.

Comment: Do you mean if you load the SVG directly (eg www.my.site/somefile.svg) then the images that weren't displaying before, now start working?

Comment: Yes sir. here is my website link: http://www.cybersourcepk.com/new/

Comment: I see there are a number of SVGs on that page. Is this problem affecting all of them?

Comment: Yes sir. But this problem arise only on safari 5.1.7.

Answer (score 0):

Safari on Windows has known issues calculating the height of responsive inline SVGs.

You might try the [intrinsic ratio](https://alistapart.com/article/creating-intrinsic-ratios-for-video) technique, whereby you position the `<svg>` tag absolutely inside an `<object>` tag with bottom padding equal to the ratio of the `viewBox` (or height/width attributes) of the svg.

```css
.my-responsive-svg {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  /* for an svg with a 16:9 aspect ratio */
  padding-top: 56.25%;
}

.my-responsive-svg svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<object class="my-responsive-svg">
  <svg width="160" height="90" viewBox="0 0 160 90">
    <rect x="10" y="10" width="140" height="70" />
  </svg>
</object>
```

Source: Hat tip to Sérgio Lopes who commented on [this blog post](https://benfrain.com/attempting-to-fix-responsive-svgs-in-desktop-safari/#comment-18362).